# Chartboost Interstitial shifted Up

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x, chartboost

I used Chartboost ads in Cocos2d-X iPhone game.

Chartboost fullscreen ads shifted up sometime when revmob banner on. Not able to close this.

Here is screenshot:
[image]

Code:

```
   [[RevMobAds session] showBanner];
   [[Chartboost sharedChartboost] showInterstitial];
```

How to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the SDKs are conflicting when showing the views. As I don't know much about how RevMob shows their view, I suggest simply not showing both at the same time. Instead, do the following:

When the user loads the menu screen, call the Chartboost interstitial code:

[[Chartboost sharedChartboost] showInterstitial:CBLocationMainMenu];

Then, call the RevMob code when the Chartboost interstitial is closed by implementing the didCloseInterstitial delegate method:

`- (void)didCloseInterstitial:(CBLocation)location {
    if (location == CBLocationMainMenu) {
        [[RevMobAds session] showBanner];
    }
}`